# Wordpress website index.php is injected with malware and code regenerated once deleted and wp-admin is not access

Tags: wordpress, malware

Problem 1: can not access to wp-admin even top logedined bar is visible and body with 500 error as show in picture below
[black page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOAlw.png)
[Home page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0VIB.png)

Problem 2: can not delete the malware from index.php it again regenerate when refresh as show in the pic.
[Index.php file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcJgR.png)
Problem 3: user automatically added to database.
[user table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vvpd.png)

.htacces file [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZoXF.png)

index.php in wp-admin [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzpbA.png)

Comment: another problem of the website is when some one click on its google sitemap then it linked to another website url instead of this one

Comment: please post code fragments as code snippets instead of images

Answer (score 2):

1.Delete all files and folders in your public_html except for:

- wp-content
- wp-config.php

2.Upload fresh WordPress files instead of deleted files.

3.You will be able to login to Admin Dashboard now.

4.Install Wordfence plugin, perform a Quick Scan.

5.There will be infected plugins/themes, you need to replace them and rescan your site until scan shows no malwares.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You Have Change Server and Then Try

1.Upload fresh WordPress files Delete Old Wp Files

2.You will be able to login to Admin Dashboard now.

3.Install Wordfence plugin, perform a Quick Scan.
4.Update Theme And Plugin

It Works